# Not able to display html table position from php,mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, if-statement

Hello i have 2 html tables Fahrzeuge and News which i called as widgets and i have store their positions in database and depending on their position they should display. So table with position 1 always display at top and table with position 2 display at last. I have written this code but its not displaying according to their table position. Just a small mistake i am doing somewhere not able to identify.
Here is my database table:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
$Position=1;
    $sql="Select position,dsnr_dashboard_widget from dashboard_widget_users where dsnr_yw_user=10";
    $sql_results=mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_results)){
    $widget=$row['dsnr_dashboard_widget'];
    $position=$row['position'];
    if(($widget==1)&&($position==2)){
    $page['content'] .= '<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
        <tr>
            <td id="fahrzeuge">

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>';
    }
    else(($widget==2)$$($position==1)){ 
    $page['content'] .= '<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
        <tr>
            <td id="news">

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>';
    }
```

Comment: use order by in positioning, that can help $sql = "Select position,dsnr_dashboard_widget from dashboard_widget_users where dsnr_yw_user=10 ORDER BY position ASC"; then the first position row will be loaded first.

Comment: yes its working i  understood it was small mistake :) thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
$sql="Select position,dsnr_dashboard_widget from dashboard_widget_users where dsnr_yw_user=10 ORDER BY position";
```

Comment: thanks man before your answer only i tried and it was working for me :) but anyway thanks for your answer its the right solution